# Zend Framework 2 - RoleUserBridge module

Tags: zend-framework2

I use RoleUserBridge to create a role user but when I registre I have this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   ZfcUser\Mapper\UserHydrator::__construct() must implement interface
>   Zend\Crypt\Password\PasswordInterface, none given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\zf2\vendor\roleuserbridge\Module.php on line 51 and
>   defined in
>   C:\wamp\www\zf2\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Mapper\UserHydrator.php
>   on line 21

In the user_role_linker I use colums => (id,role_id,is_default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module is not up to date.
Change "vendor/roleuserbridge/Module.php" line 51 to:

$mapper->setHydrator($sm->get('zfcuser_user_hydrator'));